# unable to coredump - embedded linux

Tags: embedded-linux, coredump

i did ulimit -c unlimited / some number
proc... core_pattern is core
and my rootfs and the apps are all debugversion [ not the kernel though] 
any idea why iam unable to get coredumps on kill -SIGABRT/SEGV pid

thanks
Furion.

Comment: i used prctl in the program and alls good now ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used prctl in the program to explicitly enable core dump (it sounds like a script is disabling coredumps ) and alls good now

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to create the core using gdb as follows?

```
$ gdb --pid=1234
(gdb) gcore
Saved corefile core.1234
(gdb) detatch
```

gdb doesn't care about the settings.
If you are wondering what is detach.
Since you have attached the process to gdb, detatch it using gdb control using detatch command

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if core dumps are enabled for your kernel:

```
CONFIG_ELF_CORE=y
```

Here's some [documentation](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/ELF_CORE.html) of the configuration item.

Comment: my test program is able to core dump on the same box.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the current directory (getcwd()) of the process is writable by the process and contains enough space to hold the core dump file.

Comment: i make the whole rootfs 777 :) .... my test program dumps core though... and i have lot of space... but my big fat application which somebody else wrote [ am just maintaing] doesnt dump i tried SIGSEGV SIGABRT etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the application in question itself changes the core dump size  ?

Comment: o i did prctl SET_DUMPABLE in main something happens like a signal handler etc ? what is the command to check what signal handers are written for a running program ?